# Arduino IDE crashes without any warning

Tags: arduino-ide

I'm a beginner in Arduino. I just installed Arduino IDE (arduino-1.0.5-r2-windows) but when I try to run its not responding and crashes after few minutes. I tried re-installing it and removing the temporary files but none of those helped.

Can anyone tell me what causes this problem and how to debug it?

Comment: It might be helpful to know some more details about your system, e.g. what version of Windows are you using? Is it 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: Additionally, what does "crash" mean? Any error messages? Slows down? After a specific action?

Comment: Not really a fix, but you might want to try an older version of the IDE.

Comment: And if you run it from a terminal?

Comment: The ide was slow and closes after sometime without any notice. I didn't try running it from terminal. But I switched to arduino 1.5.6 , it works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Installing Arduino 1.5.6 solved the issue.